# How to update_attributes w/ UNIX Timestamp and set MySQL DATETIME automatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, unix-timestamp

I just assumed that some rails magic would automatically convert an incoming post w/ a unix time 1345069440000 to the appropriate datetime on the backend. However, I have a model Event with a datetime called "start_at" and:

```
 e = Event.new()
 e.start_at = 1345069440000
 e.save
```

It seems to send the 1345069440000 straight through and then mysql nulls it.  Same with a ruby time

```
 e = Event.new()
 e.start_at = 1345069440
 e.save
```

if I set it to some arbitrary strings, it does a better job of inferring:

```
e.start_at = '1/1344/12'
e.save
```

sets the date to '1334-12-01 00:00:00 UTC +00:00". So, it's making an attempt.

Clearly I can override the setter in my class, but I was hoping to change this behavior much higher up so that all controllers would support unix times for any datetime being passed up.

Rails 3.2, Ruby 1.9.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this code from `active_record/attribute_methods/time_zone_conversion.rb` is attempting to do the conversion:

```
unless time.acts_like?(:time)
  time = time.is_a?(String) ? Time.zone.parse(time) : time.to_time rescue time
end
```

One option (albeit a little heavy-handed) would be to monkey-patch Fixnum to add a .to_time method:

```
def to_time
  Time.at(self)
end
```